Drawbacks of reducing number of roots in SHA-256?
i currently implement SHA-256 in GO, i know that by standard we have to use roots of first 64 prime numbers, but i am curious how reducing this number can affect protection of an algorithms.
Right now i have implemented variation with 24 prime numbers. If we stay with all standards, the number of computations by brute force is equal to 2 in power of 256, will there be any drawbacks besides reduced number of computations?
var k = []uint32{
    0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
    0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
    0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
}


Lets take it point by point, from most obvious to less:

Reducing NOR(Number of Roots) lead to loss in complexity, making it more predictable
Collision/Preimage Attacks:
Than less NOR are, than higher chance to fall into collision and lost determinism of hash function
Not compatible with standard; can be incompatible with regular SHA-256 algorithm
It is not proved yet, but cryptographic hash functions still can be decrypted in reverse order in some way. Therefore reducing NOR may lead it decryption
Loss of "completely different" output with small change of input

Solution:

Simply increase NOR or amount of iteration over first steps to achieve required amount of complexity

